# How to get a singleton injection in a class with Dagger in android

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

There is the DataAccessInterface class that is in charge of managing the database:

```
public class DataAccessInterface {

    private DaoSession daoSession;
    public DataAccessInterface () {
    }
...
     public void saveCar (Car car) {
         daoSession.getCarDao (). insert (car);
     }
}
```

DataAccessInterface injection is used in several Fragments with success. Example:

```
public class LoginFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Inject
    DataAccessInterface dataAccessInterface;

...
    public boolean initDatabase () throws SyncDataBaseException {
        try {
            dataAccessInterface.openSession (currentUser.getUsername ());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SyncDataBaseException ();
        }
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

There is a BackendImp class (No Fragment or Activity) that in the background queries a rest service and saves the response in the database. The injection does not work, it is always null:

```
public class BackendImp {
    @Inject
    DataAccessInterface dataAccessInterface;

public void save () {
Car car = unloadCar ()
dataAccessInterface.saveCar (car);
}
```

The AbstractActivityComponent looks like this

```
@PerActivity
@Component (dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface AbstractActivityComponent {

   Activity activity ();
    final class Initializer {
        public static AbstractActivityComponent init (Activity activity) {
            return DaggerAbstractActivityComponent.builder ()
                    .applicationComponent (DaggerManager.getInstance (). appComponent ())
                    .activityModule (new ActivityModule (activity))
                    .build ();
        }
    }
    void inject (LoginFragment inject);
    void inject (BackendImp inject);
}
```

ApplicationModule:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private final Application application;
    private final User currentUser;

    public ApplicationModule (Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        this.currentUser = getUser ();
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataAccessInterface dataAccessInterface () {
        return new DataAccessInterface (userProfile ());
    }
}
```

And ApplicationComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(Application application);

    final class Initializer {

        public static ApplicationComponent init(Application app) {
            return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(app))
                    .build();
        }
    }

    Application application();
    Context context();
    DataAccessInterface dataAccessInterface();
}
```

**Error:
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.service.DataAccessInterface.saveCar(Car)' on a null object reference**

**Edit:**

Based on Nitrodon's question in the comments:
The BackendImp functions are called from a Worker, since they will be done every hour. I wanted a single instance so I did the following which is probably wrong:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

   public static BackendService backendService;

   @Override
   public void onCreate () {
         
      super.onCreate ();
      backendService = new BackendImp ();
  }

  public static void callWorker () {
      ...
   
      workManager.enqueue (updateWorkRequest);
  }
```

And the Worker:

```
public class updateWorker extends Worker {
   ...

   @Override
   public Result doWork () {
         Result result = Result.retry ();

         try {
            backend = MainApp.backendService;
             backend.save ();
             result = Result.success ();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             result = Result.retry ();
         }
         return result;
     }
```

Comment: How are you obtaining an instance of `BackendImp`?

Comment: Very good observation. I had not considered that it could influence. I get backendImp with a new in MainApp which I then use to call its functions. backendService = new BackendImp (); Is that the problem? how should i do it? I will edit the question with the missing code

Answer (score 0):

Dagger doesn't hook into constructor calls.  You have to tell Dagger to inject dependencies into `BackendImp`.

You have an `inject(BackendImp inject)` method in your activity component.  This would work, but it's in the wrong place, so your application class can't access it.  Putting this method in the application component would work:

```java
   @Override
   public void onCreate () {
         
      super.onCreate ();
      backendService = new BackendImp();
      // I assume you created the application component somewhere in here.
      component.inject(backendService);
  }
```

However, members injection methods are generally discouraged where they can be avoided.  There's no other choice in `Activity` subclasses, since they are instantiated by the framework, but something like `BackendImp` is entirely under your control, so you can and should let Dagger create it for you.

To do this, place `BackendImp` itself in the application component by giving it the `@Singleton` scope and an `@Inject` constructor:

```java
@Singleton
public class BackendImp {
    final DataAccessInterface dataAccessInterface;

    @Inject
    BackendImp(DataAccessInterface dataAccessInterface) {
        this.dataAccessInterface = dataAccessInterface;
    }

    // ...
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    // ...

    // Use this in your application instead of new BackendImp()
    BackendImp backendImp(); 

    // Many tutorials instead suggest making an @Inject field in
    // your application and calling inject(application).
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "place BackendImp itself in the application component". all the class? Could you provide some reference, this would be of great help to better understand your answer.